# Adding numbers from 1 to N in C#

Tags: c#, while-loop

I'm writing code in C# and trying to add all of the numbers between the number 1 and N, N being the number that is inputted in a textbox.  I'm doing this, at least trying to do this, by putting it into a while loop.

I have added all the numbers between 2 textboxes before but for some reason I'm driving myself crazy and can't figure this out. I'm a beginning programmer so please be gentle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
One of the six thousand things I've tried.  I think this has me in an infinite loop?

```
       private void btnAddAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           int n;
           int count = 0;
           int answer = 0;

           n = int.Parse(txtNum.Text);

           count = n;

           while (count >= 1)
           {
               answer = answer + count;
               count++;
           }
               lstShow.Items.Add("Sum = " + answer);
               lstShow.Text = answer.ToString();
       }
```

Comment: are we doing your homework for you ?

Comment: Ugh, no. I'm doing this as homework but I don't want the answer. I specified that in my last question, because I know I'll never learn that way. I have just been sitting here for at least a half hour trying to figure this out. Just looking for pointers.

Comment: You are more likely to get a more complete answer if you provide some code to show what you have tried and what isn't working.  No code on an obvious homework question is not going to result in much in the way of answers

Comment: I edited my question and added it in.  Like I said, I'm not looking for an answer.  I'm a beginning programmer who honestly really doesn't know what she's doing just yet.

Comment: Thats the way to do it man hope you find your answer

Comment: In case you didn't know the sum of 1...n is n(n+1)/2

Comment: There's [a good youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxiObVwQ8MM) that I stumbled across that talks about this exact subject. The instructor talks about using recursion to solve the problem. (The lecture is in C, but the general programming ideas are there)

Comment: There's a "subtle" bug in all the answers posted thus far. I didn't watch all of the video posted by @IchabodClay but it looks like it made the same bug as well.

Answer (score 10):

Why not use Gauss formula. (N*(N+1))/2

```
private void btnAddAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int n, answer;  
     n = int.Parse(txtNum.Text);
     answer = (n*(n+1))/2;
     lstShow.Items.Add("Sum = " + answer);
     lstShow.Text = answer.ToString();
}
```

Comment: +1 for this Moe. Console.WriteLine(((N*(N+1))/2).ToString());

Answer (score 4):

If you change the `++` to a `--` it should work as you want it to.

```
   int n;
   int count = 0;
   int answer = 0;

   n = 3;

   count = n;

   while (count >= 1)
   {
       answer = answer + count;
       count--; // here was the error
   }

   Console.WriteLine (answer);
```

Output: 6

Also, just for a point of additional interest you can use That uses [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) and [Enumerable.Sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) instead of the while loop (probably goes beyond what is expected for a homework but it's useful to know what's out there).

```
answer =  Enumerable.Range(1, n).Sum();
```

Comment: it might be a dumb question, but for the sake of learning, why would i use that? it works, i'm just curious. thanks by the way.

Comment: sorry, by *that* i meant --. i should have been more clear, but i read a comment from up above and figured it out.

Comment: don't worry about it - just don't give up and it will get easier - having something like SO to get help is good advantage compared to learning when I was in school :)

Comment: also note that `count--` is nothing but a shortcut for `count = count - 1`

Answer (score 3):

Your edit: you should **decrement** count..
Another edit, it appears I need to explain more:
By **decrement** I mean `--`. The post or pre decrement operator decreases the value by 1.

If count keeps increasing by 1, **count >=1** will never be met. You need to reduce **count** to 1.. hence `count--;`

Also I suggest you use `TryParse(string,out int) ;` or at least wrap the `Parse` call in a `try catch block`.

Here is a pointer in pseudocode:

```
GetInput From User
TryParse Input
If Between 1 and N
Declare sum = 1;

for i to N-1 
   sum+=i; 

/* if you don't want to use the for loop
  while i < N 
  sum+=i;
  inc i; */
Print sum
```

Comment: if "between" means "(1..N) except border numbers" then you should start from 2, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging is an important skill for any programmer.  There are some good tools in Visual Studio to help with debugging.

A good way to debug your code when you are stuck is to use 'breakpoints' and step through the code.

Select the line you want your code to stop at (e.g. `n = int.Parse(txtNum.Text);`) and press F9 - this will add a breakpoint at this line.

Now, when you run your programme, it will stop at the breakpoint.  If you press F11, you can 'step' through the code one line at a time.  You can hold your mouse over a variable to see its value while you are doing this.

You will quickly find the problem in your code if you do this.